# Route perform wrong action on submit form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

i'm having trouble with my rails aplication.

i have a form who should submit some fields to be search to /cities/search/<params_here>.
[image: form]

but, when i submit form, the routing goes to wrong action, and perform a set_city funcion... (??? why this happens ??? ) [image: Query]

[image: routes.rb]

if the route exists and be declared before the other routes generates from :resources, that should't work?

[image: cities#search]

Comment: [Please post code, config, errors, etc as formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are two problems with the above code.

1.The URL in the `form_with`:

The URL ideally should be `url: "cities/search",`.
Since you are using `form_with`, the values will be available in the form of query params.
This is where our 2nd change comes in.

2.The route that you've set:

It should be `get '/cities/search', to: 'cities#search'`, and as mentioned above, the form fields and their values will be available in the query params.

In the cities_controller's search action, you'd get the params by using `params[:query]` and `params[:search]`.
Please check [form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) once so that you get a clear idea of it's working.

I have not tested this, so let me know if this helps and if there are any other issues after the above changes.
Also, it is good practice to post the code in the questions in text format rather than images. Ref. [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a collection route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) without needing to think about route priority:

```
resources :cities do
  get 'search', on: :collection
end
```